# Find alphabetic value based on numeric rule

Tags: java

I have a formula that can be used to convert a three-letter triplet into a numerical value:

```
some triplet = a(26^2) + b(26) + c = some numerical value
```

In this formula, a, b, and c each correspond to their respective letter's index of the alphabet. For example:

```
DOG = 3*(26^2) + 14*26 + 6 = 2398
```

I need to be able to invert this process and produce a triplet given a numerical value. For instance, if given the value 1371, I should produce CAT. Could anyone explain the algorithm for doing so? I'm writing the code to do so in Java, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Christian XD don't know if it was sarcastic. Nevertheless, love it

Comment: Solve a quadratic equation?

Comment: Not really solving a quadratic equation. Cause `x` is already there, coefficients are missing. Looks like he needs three linear equations. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This question should be posted in [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange

Comment: @Mr.Singh yes. There are 3 unknown variables.

Comment: @Mr.Singh - I think you mean PrimarySchoolMath stack exchange.  HTH :-)

Comment: @StephenC You cracked me up :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of finding remainders:

```
int num;
int c = num % 26;
num = (num - c) / 26;
int b = num % 26;
int a = (num - b) / 26;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity. Can't there be more than 1 solution for this?

Comment: @christian if you mean a general solution to a quadratic, yes, but the solution OP want is only for positive integers (the ascii codes of the letters), in which case there's only one solution,